# Python: selenium and beautifulsoup how to handle lazy-load-like webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

Using selenium and beautifulsoup to scratch data from AgilePLM(Oracle),
if item lists is too long, then it needs mouse scrolling to load data to the DOMs,
which means data won't be completely loaded to html until manually scrolling the lists one by one to the end.

By sending a END key to directly scroll to the end is no sense and will lose the items in the middle.

Is there any method to achieve this demand? like other lazy-load-like pages?

Comment: You can scroll down in selenium too (https://www.guru99.com/scroll-up-down-selenium-webdriver.html), and you should use the concepts of selenium waits ( https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html ) to wait until the element that you want is visible on the screen and then perform the rest of the logic.

Comment: Edit: @Duy Banh has already answered the question below, using java, python should be similar to them, as they use the same classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't know how to code on Python, but this is my Java code for scrolling to an element in a lazy load list.

```
public boolean scrollDownUntilElementVisible(By scrollableElement, By targetElement, By loadSpinner, int timeoutInSeconds) {

    ExpectedCondition expectedElement = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(targetElement);
    ExpectedCondition waitForLoading = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadSpinner);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds, 1);
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    WebElement element = findElement(scrollableElement);
    String script = "arguments[0].scrollBy(0, arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().height)";

    wait.until(driver -> {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds, 100).until(waitForLoading);
        try {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 1, 100).until(expectedElement);
            return true;
        } catch (TimeoutException ignored) {
        }
        executor.executeScript(script, element);
        return false;
    });
    return false;
}
```